# Is this implementation of C# Weak Interning Cache Table threadsafe and memorysafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, weak-references

I searched a lot on the internet to find a C# implementation that could allow to cache immutable objects using weak references in order to reduce the memory footprint (similar to .NET String.Intern).

In my case, I need to cache multiple list of products and the same product can be present in each list:

- Total amount of products in the database is 7 millions
- We end up with 10 millions objects in memory after loading everything
- After removing duplicates, it drops to 3 millions, meaning that caching those objects would reduce the memory footprint significantly.

I have found an old post asking for such feature but nobody was able to propose an implementation [Any weak interning collections (for immutable objects)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923682/any-weak-interning-collections-for-immutable-objects)

I have made an implementation but I need to be sure it is production-ready and that there is no race condition or other threading issue hidden into this code.

```
// Inspired by: http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2014/01/08/WeakTable.aspx
public static class ObjectCache<T> where T : class
{
    #region Inner classes

    public enum ElementState : byte
    {
        Uninitialized = 0,
        Initialized = 1,
        Finalized = 2
    }

    private class Element
    {
        public readonly T Value;
        public ElementState State;

        public Element(T value)
        {
            State = ElementState.Uninitialized;
            Value = value;
        }

        ~Element()
        {
            if (State == ElementState.Initialized)
            {
                State = ElementState.Finalized;
                WeakReference<Element> state;
                Values.TryRemove(this, out state);
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    private class WeakEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<object>
    {
        private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> _innerComparer;

        public WeakEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> innerComparer)
        {
            _innerComparer = innerComparer;
        }

        public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            if (x == y) return true;

            var xRef = x as WeakReference<Element>;
            var xElem = xRef == null ? x as Element : GetTarget(xRef);

            var yRef = y as WeakReference<Element>;
            var yElem = yRef == null ? y as Element : GetTarget(yRef);

            if (xElem == yElem) return true;
            if (xElem == null || yElem == null) return false;

            // If xState is finalized, then we are within the Finalizer and we want to
            // search by reference to specifically remove this item.
            if (xElem.State == ElementState.Finalized) return false;

            // If we are looking for an element but this one is currently being finalized,
            // we dont want to return it because it is going to disappear from the cache soon.
            if (xElem.State == ElementState.Uninitialized && yElem.State == ElementState.Finalized) return false;

            return _innerComparer.Equals(xElem.Value, yElem.Value);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(object obj)
        {
            return obj is WeakReference<Element>
                ? (GetTarget((WeakReference<Element>) obj)?.GetHashCode() ?? obj.GetHashCode())
                : obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    #endregion Inner classes

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, WeakReference<Element>> Values = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, WeakReference<Element>>(new WeakEqualityComparer(EqualityComparer<T>.Default));

    public static int Count => Values.Count;

    public static T Intern(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return null;

        Element initialElement = new Element(item);
        WeakReference<Element> weakInitialState = new WeakReference<Element>(initialElement, true);
        Element newElement;
        do
        {
            newElement = GetTarget(Values.GetOrAdd(weakInitialState, x =>
            {
                initialElement.State = ElementState.Initialized;
                return weakInitialState;
            }));
        } while (newElement == null);

        return newElement.Value;
    }

    public static TRef GetTarget<TRef>(WeakReference<TRef> value) where TRef : class
    {
        TRef target;
        value.TryGetTarget(out target);
        return target;
    }
}
```

In this code, there is a WeakReference with trackRessurection active held against every item and when one of them is garbage collected, the finalized is catched and used to clean itself from the ConcurrentDictionary. I have identified the following cases that could be problematic:

- Two threads try to add the same item at the same time (should be handled by the ConcurrentDictionary)
- An item is being finalized while another thread tries to Intern the same item (should be handled by the Equals and the while loop)

Is there any other weird condition?

Comment: This question probably belongs in code review; you’ll get better answers there. Your code apparently works well and you dont have a specific problem that needs to be solved so I’m voting to close.

Comment: Oops, I didnt know about codereview.stackexchange.com. I just reposted my question there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180811/is-this-implementation-of-c-weak-interning-cache-table-threadsafe-and-memorysaf

Comment: "You need to submit to stack overflow. Code that requires changes for correctness are not suitable for code review site." LOL

Comment: Yeah, I feel like being bounced between the two sites. I guess the fact I didnt state any particuliar issue but I did mention there could be some disqualified it for both stackoverflow and codereview.

Comment: This is a true vicious circle. My tip: delete this question and as a new one, but this time with code that does not work. Implement a bug in your code so that it deadlocks or break it otherwise and it'll be on topic here. Then ask how to fix that and how to implement something else. Or ask how to test it to verify whether it works correctly. This should be on-topic here too.