# Hash-consing in F# and weak hash tables in .net

Tags: .net, f#, hashmap, hashset

[Hash-consing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) consists in keeping in memory only one copy of a given object ; that is, if two objects are semantically equal (same content) then they should be physically equal (same location in memory). The technique is usually implemented by keeping a global hash set and creating new objects only if they are not equal to an object in the hash set.

An additional requirement is that objects in the hash table should be collectable if they are not referenced by anything except the hash table; otherwise said, the hash table should contain weak references.

The issue is furthermore complicated by the need to have constant time, thus shallow, hashing and equality tests ; thus objects have a unique identifier that is incremented when a new object is added to the table.

I have a working implementation that uses `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<key, node>` where `key` is a tuple giving a shallow summary of the node (suitable for default hashing and equality test) and `node` is the object. The only problem is that the `Dictionary` keeps strong references to the nodes !

I could use a `Dictionary` to `WeakReference`'s but this would not free the keys pointing to dangling references.

Some advocate using `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable` but this class seems to do the opposite : it frees the value when the key is collected, whereas I need to free the key when the value is collected.

One could try using `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable<node, node>` but I would need custom hashing and equality tests... and `ConditionalWeakTable` is documented *not* to use the `GetHashCode()` virtual method, instead using the default hashing function.

Thus my question : is there some equivalent of `Dictionary` that would keep weak references to values and free the keys when the references become dangling ?

Comment: Do you need to free the key immediately when the value is collected? Or could you relax the requirement and just free the key at some later point in time?

Comment: I do not need them to be freed immediately — it's just that I don't want them to accumulate and uselessly consume lots of memory. I've thought about running another thread to periodically kill keys with dangling references, but this seems complicated and prone to concurrency errors.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also have an OCaml implementation using the hash table from the `Weak` module, and a Java implementation usiong `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: Could you implement weak hashtables in F# using the OCaml code as a reference implementation? IIRC the weak hashset uses weak arrays, which could be implemented w/ Array<WeakReference>.

Comment: @monniaux: Nice to see you here. After our brief talk last year, it's great to see you pick up F#. Let us know how it works for you :).

Comment: It seems to be related: [Compacting a WeakReference Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2047591/55209)

Comment: Also, `DependentHandle` may help: [Ephemerons in .NET and C#](http://blog.gx.weltkante.de/2012/08/ephemerons-in-net-and-c.html)

Comment: @Artem: I thought about running some kind of cleanup thread to kill keys mapped to dangling references. This seems complicated, and introduces threading (with all associated problems: proper locking, etc.). Maybe there is a way to synchronize it to the GC, but I don't know about .net GC internals (and perhaps they depend on the platform).

Comment: There is probably some problem with this which I haven't considered, but have you tried using some form of the hash value of your objects as the key for the CWT?  Then you would simply have to write a class to wrap the CWT which uses the hash to check if the object already exists.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that CWT does not solve the hash-consing problem because it begs the question - its keys assume reference equality. However, it might be worth pointing out that CWT does not hold on to keys or values. Here is a little test:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

let big () =
    ref (Array.zeroCreate (1024 * 1024) : byte [])

let test1 () =
    let d = Dictionary(HashIdentity.Reference)
    for i in 1 .. 10000 do
        stdout.WriteLine(i)
        let big = big ()
        d.Add(big, big)
    d

let test2 () =
    let d = ConditionalWeakTable()
    for i in 1 .. 10000 do
        stdout.WriteLine(i)
        let big = big ()
        d.Add(big, big)
    d
```

On my machine, `test1` runs out of memory and `test2` succeeds. It seems that this would only happen if CWT did not hold on to keys as well as values.

For hash-consing, your best bet might be what Artem is suggesting in the comments. If this sounds too complicated, it also makes a lot of sense to just give the user control, say:

```
let f = MyFactory() // a dictionary with weak reference values hidden inside
f.Create(..) : MyObject // MyObject has no constructors of its own
f.Cleanup() // explicitly cleans up entries for collected keys
```

Then you do not need to introduce threading, study how GC internals work, or do any magic. The user of the library may decide where it is appropriate to clean up or simply "forget" the factory object - which would collect the whole table.

Comment: I tried using CWT but it appeared that data put inside the table was collected immediately (because the value is collected as soon as the key becomes unreachable). Have you tried recovering data from a CWT? It is impossible to use CWT from A to A because CWT does *not* use the hashcode function from the data type, but instead calls the default hash function, which is unsuitable for hash-consing (one needs shallow hashing with unique identifiers). One solution would be to copy the CWT source code and adapt it.

Comment: @monniaux: yes, I agree that CWT is not suitable for hash consing.  OCaml weak table clearly wins here. Recovering data from a CWT is fine though if you hold on to the keys - this is what it's been designed for. Yes, post here if you find a good solution or write your own - for hash-consing.